# Compiling single cs file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting to learn C# and I'm following some book's examples.

I want to try out some basic console app, so I did a new cs file with VS and now I just want to compile it to try it.

But for some reason, the build/debug/compile options are all disabled. What must I do to compile my app from VS?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Project not individual files are compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select "File menu, New, Project...", Then "Visual C#, Windows, Console Application".

You may have done "File, New, File..." instead.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new project, not a new .cs file.  File + New + Project, Windows, Console Application.